# smuggling macro out of a group in tex core results in undefined control sequence

Tags: tex-core, expansion, grouping, scoping

I am trying to re-apply changes done in a group directly afterwards with the following code similar [to the approach in here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf)

```
\def\smuggle#1\endgroup{%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\edef\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}
\begingroup
  \def\variable{12}
  \edef\variable{\variable34}
  \edef\variable{\variable56}
  \def\var {A}%
  \edef\changes{%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\variable{\variable}%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\var{\var}%
  }%
  \smuggle\changes
\endgroup
\message{\meaning\changes}
\changes
\message{value of \variables , \vars }
\end
```

However, when compiling it, I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\changes ->\def \variable 
                          {123456}\def \var {A}
\smuggle ... \edef \expandafter #1\expandafter {#1
                                                  }
l.14 \endgroup
```

and I am not exactly sure how to interpret this.
Is `\changes` or one of `\variable` or `\var` undefined? or is there some problem with the expansion?
AFAIK this should expand to

```
\endgroup
\edef\changes{%
    \def\variable{123456}%
    \def\var{A}%
}%
\message{ [...]
```

but this doesn't seem to be the case. Can you please give me hints as to where this is not behaving as expected?

Comment: yes it does expand to that but `\edef\changes{\def\variable...` gives an error trying to expand `\variable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `\smuggle` command relies on the command being smuggled fully expands in one step

If you have `\def\foo{zzz}`  then

```
\smuggle\foo\endgroup
```

results in

```
\endgroup\def\foo{zzz}
```

so the value is preserved (or rather re-set) outside the group.

But `\changes` is defined to be

```
\def \variable {123456}\def \var {A}
```

which isn't expandable

The chain of `\expandafter` in `\smuggle` is designed to expand the token one step and is intended to be used with `\def` but you have `\edef` which causes `\variable` to expand with the error you show.

With `\def` you get:

```
\def\smuggle#1\endgroup{%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
                                    %%%
}
```

```
macro:->\def \variable {123456}\def \var {A}
```

as `\changes` is copied outside the group, but you get an error on the following

\message{value of \variables , \vars }

which is I think a typo for `\variable`

so the error free log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bb320.tex macro:->\def \variable {123456}\def \var {A} value of 123456, A )
No pages of output.
```

from

```
\def\smuggle#1\endgroup{%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}
\begingroup
  \def\variable{12}
  \edef\variable{\variable34}
  \edef\variable{\variable56}
  \def\var {A}%
  \edef\changes{%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\variable{\variable}%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\var{\var}%
  }%
  \smuggle\changes
\endgroup
\message{\meaning\changes}
\changes
\message{value of \variable , \var }
\end
```

Comment: so having the double `\edef` resulted in too much expansion and the error states that `\variable` in `\def` is not expendable by `\edef` defined in `\smuggle`; have I understood that correctly?

Comment: @FabianSchneider yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

David has already [explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619956/4427) the source of the error. Here's a different way

```
\newlinechar=`\^^J % for readable messages

\def\smuggle#1\endgroup{%
  \toks0=\expandafter{#1}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#1{\the\toks0}}\x
}
\begingroup
  \def\variable{12}
  \edef\variable{\variable34}
  \edef\variable{\variable56}
  \def\var {A}%
  \edef\changes{%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\variable{\variable}%
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\var{\var}%
  }%
  \smuggle\changes
\endgroup

\message{^^J***\noexpand\changes is \meaning\changes***^^J}

\changes

\message{^^J***value of \noexpand\variable and \noexpand\var is \variable, \var***^^J}

\end
```

The code exploits the fact that with `\the\toks0` the token list is delivered but not expanded further in `\edef`.

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=tex)
(./smuggle.tex

***\changes is macro:->\def \variable {123456}\def \var {A}***

***value of \variable and \var is 123456, A***
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on smuggle.log.
```